Prisma and typescript: how to store/retrieve irregular JSON
I have a next.js project with a postgres db managed through prisma ORM. I have a prisma model called Scene, with an attribute called layout, that has an irregular structure. A Scene's "layout" has several widgets arranged in rows and columns. Therefore, the JSON representation is something like:
    scene.layout = [{
        row: {
            col: {
                width: "65%",
                widget: Widget
            },
            col: {
                width: "35%",
                widget: Widget
            }
        },
        row: {
            col: {
                width: "50%",
                widget: Widget
            },
            col: {
                width: "50%",
                widget: Widget
            }
        }
    }]

The problem is that there are many types of widget, each of them with specific attributes, not necessarily shared by other widgets.
The question is: how can I make prisma/typescript read/write this structure and parse its contents correctly given this irregular structure?

Why is this "irregular"; what do you mean by that? Please post your current Prisma schema to show what you have tried.

This would be so much easier and faster with a normalized data design.
